# Dataflow python pickeling issue

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, pickle, apache-beam

I have written a simple dataflow program that takes input from a pub/sub topic and calculates the `fibanacci` number for that integer. However, my DoFn is not able to pickle the custom function `fibonacci` which is giving me errors when running on Dataflowrunner. Can someone help me in telling me what I am doing wrong?
Below is my pipeline code.

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, StandardOptions, SetupOptions

class Fibonacci(beam.DoFn):
    def fibonacci(self, n):
        if n < 2:
            return n
        else:
            return self.fibonacci(n-1) + self.fibonacci(n-2)
    
    def process(self, element, fib):
        import json
        # do some processing
        n = int(json.loads(element.data))
        # call fibonnaci
        return [fib(n)]

def Print(n):
    print(n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    input_subscription = 'projects/consumerresearch/subscriptions/test-user-sub'
    
    options = PipelineOptions()
    options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming=True
    options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

    raw_pubsub_data = (
        p | 'Read from topic' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription, with_attributes=True)
    )
    
    output = raw_pubsub_data | beam.ParDo(Fibonacci()) | beam.Map(Print)
    
    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `process` should be this:

```
process(self, element):
```

Your implementation has a 3rd parameter `fib`; Beam would not know what to pass for this. Change your implementation to reference `self.fibonacci`?

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo